# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to write a simple RESTful service using Spring Boot. However, there is an error message I am not able to solve. I have been researching and it looks like it is a conflict between SpringBoot versions, however I am not sure about how can I get rid of it.

I have this SpringBootApp:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * REST Service application
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Associated with this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.websystique.springmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
        <spring.batch.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version> <!-- Or whatever JUnit you're using. -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <finalName>Spring4MVCHelloWorldRestServiceDemo</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Looks fine for me, but I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment
    at com.application.Application.main(Application.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Use the _<dependencyManagement>_ mechanism to avoid conflicts and duplicates, take off the <exclusions> from the spring batch dependency

Comment: 1 right click on project>maven>update projecrt(force update snapshot) 
2 maven clean & maven install then try

Comment: Had a "sighting" of this was overcome once by clearing the ~/.m2/repository dir...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Recommended Approach**

1. Go to [Spring boot Initialzr](https://start.spring.io/) site and select web stack as a dependency as shown in below [image: figure].
2. As Spring Boot uses the concept of **Opinionated dependencies and Bill of Materials**, It will automatically pull the other dependencies and resolve your classNotFoundException issue. And in your case it misses out the Spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar dependency.
3. Execute the Maven Goal as **clean install spring-boot:run -e** and you can find your maven dependencies in your IDE and below given is a sample POM file.

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>demo</name>
       <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
      </parent>

       <properties>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
          <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-       8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
         < /dependency>
       </dependencies>

     <build>
       <finalName>demo</finalName>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
       </build>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot is running -

```
<spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

For -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

While you are importing -

```
    <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
```

You can confirm on the master pom -

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

Can you update the spring version in your pom? Or deal with managing maven dependencies

Comment: Thanks. I added it and rebuild, but it says "Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE"

Comment: Did you run clean? Im checking the pom imports - you could remove core from yours, just checking the others

Comment: You could either remove the web dependencies, or remove the version - then they will inherit from the bom

Answer (score 2):

Delete the springframework folder in repository, then press Alt + F5 and update the project (force update snapshot).

```
C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework
```

Answer (score 0):

changed the boot-starter-parent  version from 1.5.1.RELEASE to 1.4.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Please expand your answer. Add additional information why updating to that version would fix the problem that the op is having.

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

### Please Try this one for your parent

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Spring boot 2.1.9.RELEASE

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Added pom dependency eliminated this exception:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT** - better approach.

Also clean up of maven repository with spring dependencies resolved problem for me, there were not need to add spring-core 5.2.0.RELEASE in pom. Seems that when I had many versions of spring in repo some problem occurs. Also before again resolve dependencies dont forget clean project.

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/
```

Answer (score 0):

For me changing all

```
<version>2.4.10</version>
```

to

```
<version>2.4.3</version>
```

in pom.xml file worked.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the boot-starter-parent configuration which was runnig version 2.0.0 to 1.4.0 and I was able to run the java application and got rid of this error

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>  <!-- changed it to version 1.4.0 from 2.0.0-->
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: But downgrading to an old version is hardly a sollution to the problem that lasts for long. Can't you find something that works with a later version of spring boot starter?