# Spring Boot Application cannot be resolved to a type but I imported it in pom.xm

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have added the spring boot in pom.xml but still it is giving an error.
Can anyone help me.

It is giving error The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved

and 
SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type
[image: My Main method is]

My pom. xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>proj1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>proj1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your missing the 'spring-boot-autoconfigure' jar, not sure why. You can check if it is in .m2 directory. If yes I would delete it and reimport the project.

Comment: I tryed it it didn't worked. I tried the same code in eclipse in eclipse there is no error but is STS it is giving error.

Comment: @Archit, Linking my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron/39246493#39246493) to this question.

Comment: Does it compile if you run "mvn clean package" from the command line?

Answer (score -2):

Your pom looks almost correct, but few things to note

1. No need to add dependency 'javax.servlet-api', it is available from 'spring-boot-starter-web'
2. And you probably you may be missing the 'spring-boot-maven-plugin', it is not compulsory but you may want that in your project. Where it provides some easy maven goals for you to run.

```html
       <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

if your running eclipse you can generate your .classpath files just as usual 
**mvn eclipse:eclipse**, once done your ide should look fine

then **mvn spring-boot:run** should set your application running