External dependencies not found at runtime (Spring, JUnit)
The Maven project I am currently working on seems to fail at runtime. The external dependencies seem to be available with the associated class paths that are utilized in the project when compiled.
One problem area:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

}
Excerpt of produced output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener

I have tried explicitly declaring the necessary dependencies in the pom.xml file but this seems to be redundant as even with a clean build and those dependencies not declared, they are present in the external libraries.
It is important to note that the pom.xml file used is near identical to one I have used in another project in which it ran successfully with no faults.
Pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sg</groupId>
    <artifactId>gp-appointment-manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>h2-database</name>
    <description>Final project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>24.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


For starters remove the spring-beans and spring-aop dependencies, those are already included through the different spring-boot-starter-* dependencies you are including. Also please add the full stacktrace not just one of the messages, stacktraces contain valuable information (generally the last part and not the top message).

please have a check with below [reference]  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944244/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cannot-instantiat) helps you
