# what is reason the spring boot application doesn't read application.properties file?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

i have a maven project then i'm manually added a 'src/main/resources' directory and application.properties but it can't read the application.properties file;

How can i convert my maven project to spring boot project ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron/39246493  please use these steps to create your spring - boot application and let know.

Comment: check you jar to see if application.properties file preset

Answer (score 0):

You need to say your IDE that src/main/resources is a source folder.

- Try a maven plugin (e.g. for Eclipse http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-eclipse-plugin-2.8/eclipse-mojo.html),
- do it manually
- start your application using the maven spring-boot plugin
  `mvn spring-boot:run`
  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html