# spring boot : The import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am having a hard time with one of my test programs which I am trying to write using springboot. When I try to import the JdbcTemplate class in the DAO layer I get an error : The import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate cannot be resolved

I am not sure what I am missing, I have checked the dependency and they look fine to me. Below is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vittles</groupId>
    <artifactId>FoodFood</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>FoodFood</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Attached is the error which I get in my java file 
[image]

Also attach is the list of jar imports .
Can some one please let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Linking my answer to use Spring-boot approach, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron/39246493#39246493

Answer (score 6):

1. delete the folder ‘spring-jdbc’ from the maven repository:

> %your_path%.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc

2. open Eclipse -> right click on your project -> Maven -> Update project...

P.S. pom.xml should contain the jdbc dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks your IDE is not updating the dependencies, try run as maven project - install.

I suggest you to use [springboot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), also.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with your code but its fine, it have JdbcTemplate library class, seems like a simple error. try to update your project "right click project->maven->update project" or clean maven.