# NoClassDefFoundError in springbootadmin

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to write a simple RESTful service using Spring Boot. However, there is an error message I am not able to solve. I have been researching and it looks like it is a conflict between SpringBoot versions, however I am not sure about how can I get rid of it.

SpringAdminDemo2Application.java:

```
package com.mindtree.springadmin;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.config.EnableAdminServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
public class SpringAdminDemo2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAdminDemo2Application.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();
            http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
            http.csrf().disable();

            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login.html", "/**/*.css", "/img/**", "/third-party/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

            http.httpBasic();
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.address=localhost
server.port=2001
spring.application.name=spring-boot-demo2
security.user.name = admin
security.user.password = pass

spring.boot.admin.username= ${security.user.name}
spring.boot.admin.password = ${security.user.password}

spring.boot.admin.client.metadata.user.name = ${security.user.name}
spring.boot.admin.client.metadata.user.password = ${security.user.password}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mindtree.springadmin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-admin-demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-admin-demo2</name>
    <description>spring-admin-demo2 project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>1.5.7</spring-boot-admin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment
    at com.mindtree.springadmin.SpringAdminDemo2Application.main(SpringAdminDemo2Application.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: 'However, there is an error message I am not able to solve'. What's the actual message?

Comment: I have attached console output please have a look at it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron refer this

Comment: I have pulled it from start.spring.io after that i am getting this error